# I have a code that won't accept white spaces when keypress but it's not working.

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code:

```
<script>
      $(function() {
        $('body').on('keydown', '#distype, #val', function(e) {
          console.log(this.value);
          if (e.which === 32 &&  e.target.selectionStart === 0) {
            return false;
          }  
        });
      });

</script>
```

the #distype, #val are the id of the text input.

Comment: `e.which || e.keyCode`

Comment: Also check the value of `e.target.selectionStart`..

Answer (score 0):

You are attaching the onKeyDown Listener to body. Shouldn't be to the input itself? Also, it should be `e.which || e.keyCode`.

like so:

```
$("#distype").on("keydown", function (e){
    console.log(this.value);
      if (e.which && e.target.selectionStart === 0 || e.keyCode === 32 &&  e.target.selectionStart === 0) {
        return false;
      }  
}
```

Comment: Did you receive your this.value?

Comment: @michaelmagno If yes, you should add `else { console.log( e.which ); console.log(e.keyCode); }` behind your if statement . Then check them by using Chrome Dev Tools (f12 or right-click > inspect elements)

Comment: `e.which || e.keyCode` is not needed. jQuery normalizes them to `which`: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/